# Is there a way to get the coordinates of a marker in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to get my hands dirty on Google Maps API v3. But now I'm stuck with figuring out how to get the coordinates of a certain marker?

```
<script>

    var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(16.61096000671, 120.31346130371);
    var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: homeLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.61096000671, 120.31346130371),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map =
        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //I know that I'm the one who set the coordinates for this,
    // but how do I fetch it back?

    $('#plot').click(function(){
        homeMarker.setMap(map);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Just to have it handy, the Google Maps v3 [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) has more info about what you can do with a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
homeMarker.getPosition(); //returns a google.maps.LatLng object
```